# Imgur server randomly chooses h2 over http/1.1 and then it fails

Tags: http, http2, imgur, http-1.1

For a couple of hours I'm trying to upload a file to https://api.imgur.com/3/image but it randomly fails with `Failure  IO: Stream 3 reset with error code 1` or something equally meaningless. I was able to manage that sometimes imgur server chooses h2 over http/1.1 and those are the cases when the call fails. Here are logs (from [charles](https://www.charlesproxy.com/)) when it fails:

```
URL https://api.imgur.com/3/image
Status  Failed
Failure IO: Stream 3 reset with error code 1
Response Code   -
Protocol    HTTP/2.0
TLS TLSv1.2 (TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_GCM_SHA256)
Protocol    TLSv1.2
Session Resumed Yes (Server session resumed, client session restarted)
Cipher Suite    TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_GCM_SHA256
ALPN    h2
Client Supported    [h2, http/1.1]
Server Chosen   h2
Charles Supported   [h2, http/1.1]
```

And here are logs when it succeeded (for the success cases I forced in client to support just and only http/1.1 so imgur server cannot choose it):

```
URL https://api.imgur.com/3/image
Status  Complete
Response Code   200 OK
Protocol    HTTP/1.1
TLS TLSv1.2 (TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_GCM_SHA256)
Protocol    TLSv1.2
Session Resumed No
Cipher Suite    TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_GCM_SHA256
ALPN    http/1.1
Client Supported    [http/1.1]
Server Chosen   http/1.1
Charles Supported   [http/1.1]
```

Why imgur sometimes chooses h2 and then fails? Is this expected or documented?

Comment: Error code 1 is a protocol error. It might be a misbehaving HTTP/2 client, or imgur has a misbehaving server. https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc7540#section-7

Comment: I'm on Android, I'm using Retrofit + OkHttp as client side.